# vim syntax highlighting disappeared, help files no longer found

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Opened vim up today to something very strange --- syntax highlighting is no longer there (have not touched my vimrc) and cannot run :help for anything (says help.txt not found). Plugins seem to work though. I know this is a weird question, but does anyone have ANY clue what might be going on here?? I didn't touch any of my settings and the only that I think may have messed anything up is from restarting my computer while I had vim sessions open?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution to my problem! I was running Vim from GitBash (as usual) but for some reason today it decided to run the Git-installed vim (version 7.3) as opposed to the one I had previously set it to use, Vim 7.4. I'm not sure what made it revert to that but to resolve it I went back into the Git bin folder and edited the vim script to point to the Vim I wanted.